# Internet speed slows down at some time. What could be the reason?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ubuntu

For the last few months, my desktop computer's internet speed became somewhat unstable (ethernet connection). I thought it was an OS issue (Windows 10), but turned out it was the same on my dual-boot Ubuntu 18.04 too.

It happens occasionally and lasts for a few hours.
On Ubuntu, the network icon would have a question mark on it

[image]

On Windows, the internet speed becomes incredibly slow or display network disconnected icon sometimes

[image]

And when I plug off the ethernet cable and plug it into my laptop, everything is fine.

[image]

Do I have to replace the whole motherboard? Or is it only the network interface issue?

Answer (score 1):

It might be your router. If hard restart doesn't fix the problem. It could be your ISP's connection. You may also check for the settings of your router, make sure no bandwidth is limiting your wifi access. but in that case , an exclamation point means your device was unable to acquire dynamic IP from your router. You may reset to default your router if all else fails. Check the network cables of your router too for damages.

Comment: But it's working without any issue when I just plug the ethernet cable into another computer.

Comment: yeah there are many factors which affecting to speed.